# What kind and size screws should I use to fix a 5.5cm thick oak table?

Tags: screws

I am building a solid oak table made our of 4 boards which will have some limited space (1-2mm) in between them and I will be fixing each of these on 3 metal longitudinal bars (2*3 screws for each board).

I want to know which screws should I use and if I should maybe use threaded inserts instead in order to better control the tension and be able to
unscrew them easily if I want.

Comment: The top is only 5.5 mm thick? That seems unusually thin (~1/4" (plywood) for us Americans) for a tabletop

Comment: @sorin did you mean 5.5 cm maybe?

Comment: Yes, indeed 55mm i

Comment: I already drilled and used M5 with 35mm. If this proves not to be ok I will upgrade the holes to use M6 thread inserts which would allow me to ease mounting and unnounting..

Comment: Big, strong, screws are what you want here. You're using thick material so take advantage of the thickness and use beefy screws. Regardless of the screw you pick pre-drilling is a must and it would not hurt to also lubricate each screw with oil, soap or wax.